# Как зафиксировать высоту listView?

Tags: android, listview, height

listView заполняется программно и находится среди прочих layout. Корневым элементом является ScrollView. После отрисовки списка ему выделяется высота всего в одну строку, а остальные доступны прокруткой списка. Пробовал задавать и wrap_content и match_parent, не помогает. Как сделать чтобы список в списке отображались все строки?

Answer (score 3):

И ScrollView и ListView - скроллящиеся элементы. При помещении одного в другой начинаются конфлиты скрола - система не может понять что именно она должна скролить. А в вашем конкретном случае ListView сжимается до высоты первого элемента.

У вас 2 варианта:

1. Всё что выше `ListView` сделать его Header-ом, а всё, что ниже - Footer-ом. Это правильный вариант.
2. Задать для ListView фиксированную высоту, заранее вычислив суммарную высоту всех его элементов. Это хак и костыль - не делайте так.

Comment: По поводу конфликта скроллов согласен, но это могло быть решено блокированием прокрутки контейнера когда происходит скролл в области списка. И как раз для таки случаев, как мне кажется, и напрашивается свойство блокировки списка и полное отображение его содержимого.
Возможно я не правильно понимаю суть списков..

Answer (score 2):

1) Выставить высоту ListView программно, чтобы у нее не было возможности прокручиваться: берем высоту одного элемента и умножаем его на количество элементов

```
    int baseListViewHeight = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.size_72);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) list.getLayoutParams();
    lp.height = baseListViewHeight * items.size();
    list.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

2) Наследуемся от ListView и выставляем ему высоту там - суть та же но с другой стороны подход

```
public class NonScrollListView extends ListView {
    public NonScrollListView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public NonScrollListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public NonScrollListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        int heightMeasureSpec_custom = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(
                Integer.MAX_VALUE >> 2, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec_custom);
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = getLayoutParams();
        params.height = getMeasuredHeight();
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }
}
```

Затем используем его в разметке как обычное view

Решение на самое деле не рекомендуемое гуглом, не помню по каким причинам - что то там с производительностью, но на небольших списках вполне себя оправдывающее.

Comment: ListView очищает за собой память при убегании элементов за край экрана. Думаю, если лишить его этой возможности, задав высоту по содержимому и заполнив его картинками, то приложение может упасть по OutOfMemomryError

Comment: Прменял подобное решение на практике было все ок - нужно потетсить ваше предположение усиленно

Comment: Дополнил коммент - более вероятно упадёт при наличии изображений в элементах)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб
Честно говоря я уже почти созрел чтобы использовать программно напиханные item в виде linearLayout c тремя textView. А то как то много мороки получается =\

Answer (score 0):

Еще немного погуглив нашел такой рабочий вариант:
создаем функцию

```
public static void setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(ListView listView) {
    ListAdapter listAdapter = listView.getAdapter();
    if (listAdapter == null)
        return;

    int desiredWidth = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(listView.getWidth(), MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
    int totalHeight = 0;
    View view = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < listAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        view = listAdapter.getView(i, view, listView);
        if (i == 0)
            view.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(desiredWidth, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        view.measure(desiredWidth, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
        totalHeight += view.getMeasuredHeight();
    }
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
    params.height = totalHeight + (listView.getDividerHeight() * (listAdapter.getCount() - 1));
    listView.setLayoutParams(params);
}
```

и после установки адаптера передаем ей сам список, все!